# why does system send RST flag when try - TCP 3 way handshake in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, networking, tcp, scapy

i wanna create a TCP-3 way handshake in my ubuntu. 
i used a kali linux in a virtual machine. and in terminal of kali linux(IP- 172.16.28.130) i opened a port in "LISTEN " mode to get a connection with that machine.

```
nc -l -p 1025
```

my python code which ran in ubuntu host machine,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from scapy.all import *
import logging
logging.getLogger("scapy.runtime").setLevel(logging.ERROR)

#if i send to broadcast address : 192.168.1.255 what will happen?
def sendPacket(src, dst):
   ip = IP(dst = dst)
   port = RandNum(1024, 65535)
   SYN = ip / TCP(sport=port, dport=1025, flags="S", seq = 42)
   SYNACK = sr1(SYN, verbose=0)

   ACK = ip / TCP(sport = SYNACK.dport, dport=80, flags="A", seq = SYNACK.ack, ack = SYNACK.seq + 1)
   send(ACK)

   print "Done!!\n"

src = '1.2.3.4'
dst = '172.16.28.130'
sendPacket(src, dst)
```

the packets capture using wireshark,

```
3      172.16.28.1   172.16.28.130   TCP   54   64865 > blackjack [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0

4      172.16.28.130   172.16.28.1   TCP   60   blackjack > 64865 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=29200 Len=0 MSS=1460

7      172.16.28.1   172.16.28.130   TCP   54   64865 > blackjack [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0

8      172.16.28.1   172.16.28.130   TCP   54   64865 > http [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0

9      172.16.28.130   172.16.28.1   TCP   60   http > 64865 [RST] Seq=1 Win=0 Len=0
```

before ran the code, i changed IPtable,

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -s 192.168.1.20 -j DROP
```

when i changed the destination to , dst = "www.google.com" and destination port to, dport=80 it was working fine.

but now,
1) i could send SYN packet
2) the destination respond with SYN, ACK packets
3) **my system sends RST** 
4) i sent ACK
5) destination system reply with RST
So i can't establish a connection!!
Questions:
**1) how can i success full establish a connection
2) my source ip = "1.2.3.4", 
* but when i sent to virtual machine it shows 172.16.28.1(Broadcast ip). why?**

Answer (score 1):

> > 1) how can i success full establish a connection

Here's a guess. Change your `iptables` command to:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -s 172.16.28.1 -j DROP
```

When you connect to google.com, you are connecting through your physical Ethernet device, which has IP 192.168.x.y, so the `-s` argument matches.

When you connect to Kali, you are connecting through a virtual Ethernet device which has address 172.16.x.y, so the `-s` doesn't match.

You need to drop the RST packets from the correct output queue.

> > 2) my source ip = "1.2.3.4", * but when i sent to virtual machine it shows 172.16.28.1(Broadcast ip). why?

First, 172.16.28.1 is **not** your broadcast IP. It is the IP of your host computer's virtual Ethernet device.

The reasons why your source IP isn't appearing is that you aren't using it:

```
ip = IP(dst = dst)
```

You specify a destination address, but no source address. Some entity (scapy or the host OS IP stack, I'm not sure) is choosing a reasonable source address for you. You might try:

```
ip = IP(dst = dst, src = src)
```

and see what happens there.

Comment: the src problem solved. thanks.. but i could not establish a connection yet. i changed iptables in all ways like, "iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -s 192.168.1.7 -j DROP", iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -s 172.16.28.1 -j DROP, "iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags RST RST -s 172.16.28.130 -j DROP".....but no difference. my system sends RST . do i need to change anything in Kali ?